# Create virtual directory in SharePoint IIS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-services, iis, virtual-directory

I have a SharePoint 2013 on premise. I created a new virtual directory under the SharePoint web in IIS. I published a webservice into the new virtual directory. When accessing the .asmx it says

> The file you are attempting to save or retrieve has been blocked from this Web site by the server administrators.

Can anyone please explain me how to create a seperate virtual directory for my webservice to host under SharePoint IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to Central administration->Security->Define blocked file types->remove “asmx” file name extension from the list of blocked file types and check again.